# Attendance System marking student present/absent checkboxes, update Mysql PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Scenario: I am making an attendance system for a college, however I have been stuck on updating mysql and using checkboxes to mark a student absent or present.

So currently I have managed to filter the data I want to be shown. this is student_id, fname, lname, present. Please see the code below

```
<strong>Class Register:</strong> </br>

<?php

$test3= "SELECT * FROM course_attendance, students, courses, attendance WHERE course_attendance.course_id=courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id=attendance.week_number_id AND course_attendance.student_id= students.student_id AND courses.course_id='101' AND attendance.week_number_id='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($test3)  or die(mysql_error());


echo "</br><table border='1' align='center'><tr> <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th> <th><strong>First Name </strong></th> <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th> <th><strong>Present</strong></th> </tr> ";

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<tr><td width='100' align='center'>" .$rows['student_id'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['fname'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['lname'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['present'].  
"</td><tr width='120' align='center'>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

So currently, this shows the data: student_id, fname, lname, present.

The field 'Present' in my MySQL is a unsigned tinyint, I want to be able to make this a checkbox, which would enable the user to either mark a student present or absent and then update to mysql. Also I dont want the students id, fname and lname enabled to be edited, just the present field.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance if someone succesfully helps me , I will be forever grateful!

Comment: Some corrections for your HTML code: first line: `<br>` does not have a closing tag. Further below: You are opening another `<tr>` at the end of each row instead of closing it.

Comment: I have fixed them errors

Comment: So no one in this forum could help me !

Answer (score 2):

You can have a checkbox in a form for this:

`<input type='checkbox' class='form' value='Yes' name='checkbox_attendance'/> Present?`

Then you check for the value of that field and store it in the database:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox_attendance']) && $_POST['checkbox_attendance'] == 'Yes') {
    //Store the value of checkbox_attendance (Yes) into the database
} else {
    //Store 'No' into the database
}
```

student_id, fname, and lname won't be editable unless you make it.
There's a lot of information on PHP forms on the internet, take a look at those.

Comment: You will need to make sure that you're getting the right checkbox value for the student ID if you're pulling and saving multiple rows!

Comment: @JasjootMuhdar, what Simon is saying is that if you allow the user to edit multiple students' attendance at a time, you will need unique names for each checkbox so PHP knows which checkbox (ex: checkbox_attendance1, checkbox_attendance2) you're talking about.

Comment: Oh ok so is that bad practise, say for example a class has 30 students, would i need to create 30 individual checkboxes

Comment: It's really up to you. Generally, teachers take attendance for a class on paper, with a checklist. So having 30 checkboxes would be something they are most familiar with (instead of 1 form per student). I would recommend you have some kind of Select/deselect all though. No one wants to click 30 checkboxes manually.